# Is it possible to replace the dock (but just the dock)?

Tags: htc-desire, htc-sense, launcher

I have a HTC Desire HD and I like Sense (and the apps provided by HTC) a lot. But I really hate the default launcher (specifically the dock).

The problem is that if I change my launcher, I will lose the ability to use HTC Sense widgets. Is it possible to replace just the dock, but leave the rest of the launcher intact?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, No. The "dock" is part of the entire launcher and "home screens". They are, all the "same application". But there are widgets like most of the widgets that HTC Sense has. If you really don't like it that much, you should be able to find replacement widgets for the ones you like that work with other launchers like Launcher Pro, GO Launcher, or ADW Launcher, for example.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Yes I have tried pretty much all of the other launchers, but something is always missing. Usually the notifications don't work, or they just work only for Gmail and SMS (not regular email), plus I simply wasn't able to find replacement widgets (and I have tried a lot of them).

Answer (score 3):

Have tried [LauncherPro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fede.launcher&feature=search_result)?  The paid version has widgets that look a lot like Sense' widgets.

As far as I know, you can't just change the dock of Sense and keep the rest of the launcher.  You'd have to completely change to a new launcher.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Sense 'skin' (Menu -> Personalize -> Skin), which at least changes the dock's style, but I'm afraid if you want to keep the Sense widgets you're stuck with the Sense Launcher and its dock.